# DataTable joins c# - joins on datatable

Tags: c#, linq, join, datatable

How to use joins with dataTable? Since i am new to C#, I dont know why my code is not working. can anyone please look into this ?

```
var result = from x in clientpos.AsEnumerable()
                     join y in exec_pos.AsEnumerable()
                     on new { X1 = x.Field<string>("ClientCode"), X2 = x.Field<string>("Symbol"),
                         X3 = x.Field<string>("Expirydate"), X4 = x.Field<string>("Strikeprice") , X5 = x.Field<string>("ClientCode") }
                     equals new { X1 = y.Field<string>("ClientCode"), X2 = y.Field<string>("Symbol"),
                         X3 = y.Field<string>("Expirydate"), X4 = y.Field<string>("Strikeprice") ,
                         X5 = y.Field<string>("ClientCode")
                     }
                     select x;
```

Comment: Are you getting any error or result is not having the expected outcome. Can you please elaborate your problem?

Comment: Hi I am not getting any error but there is no rows in result variable. When i use the same query in mysql work bench it works completely fine. Could you please check the syntax ?

Comment: Does any record results based on your DataTable data if you try to manually validate?

Comment: Syntax looks fine, maybe the stringcomparison style is different ?
You are trying to get all rows from clientpos, that are equal in 4 columns with another table ?

Comment: Datatype was different from the actually table in the server. Thanks all

Answer (score 0):

The join is in the format below.  You can add addition WHERE to the query if you need to additional filtering.

```
var result = (from x in clientpos.AsEnumerable()
             join y in exec_pos.AsEnumerable() on x.Field<string>("ClientCode") equals y.Field<string>("ClientCode")
             select new { client = x, exec = y}).ToList();
```